# Best database paradigm to use

Tags: sql, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm just starting to get into web development, and I am planning a website.

This website will have users that can edit data. Think of it like a tree:

Theres the organisation (company), then under the organisation there are users. Each user can have multiple "clients", and the user can edit data about the "client" and share that data. The type of data are numbers and text mostly, and possibly some images.

What database paradigm would be best suited to this? I was thinking documents or relational. I want low-cost, but also lots of room for horizontal (and possible vertical) scaling.

Thanks :)

Comment: You have pretty aptly described a relational data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your requirement, Google `Cloud SQL` will be the best option for you. It provides `data manipulation` option and `horizontal scaling`.

> Google Cloud SQL is a fully-managed database service that offers high performance, scalability, and convenience. Hosted on Google Cloud Platform, Cloud SQL provides a database infrastructure for applications running anywhere.